# Do not understand step in solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Hey, I am doing revision before exam and I do not understand the
> following differential equation:
>
> $y^{''}+\frac{2(y^{'})^{2}}{1-y}=0$

Solution:

We multiply it by $\frac{1}{y^{'}}$ so we got:

$\frac{y^{''}}{y^{'}}+\frac{2y^{'}}{1-y}=0$

But then we did some step and we got:

$(\ln \left ( y^{'} \right ))^{'}-2(\ln (1-y))^{'}=0$

Can someone please explain me how?

Comment: $\dfrac{d \ln g(y)}{dy}=\dfrac {dg}{dy}\dfrac 1{g(y)}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: The formula for [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) follows from the chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\ln f(x)$

Comment: Oh, okay, but in the first term I have $\frac{y^{''}}{y^{'}}$

Comment: Derivate of denominator is on numerator.

Comment: @PeterF.:   You may see it more easily if you let $z=y'$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you

Answer (score 1):

We have by the chain rule $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$ then $(\ln(y'(x))'=\frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}$ and $-2(\ln(1-y(x)))'=-2\frac{-y'(x)}{1-y(x)}=\frac{2y'(x)}{1-y(x)}$ as required.

See [derivatives of logarithmic functions](https://brilliant.org/wiki/derivative-of-logarithmic-functions/).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the derivative of the log of a function is its reciprocal and then to complete we must still apply the Chain Rule of differentiation, multiplying the previous result with its derivative.